# $C^1$ manifold curve with bounded derivative has limit

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curves, complete-spaces

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold (not necessarily complete) and consider $\gamma : [0,1) \to \mathcal{M}$ a differentiable curve with bounded derivative, i.e., there exists constant $L>0$ such that

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\|\gamma'(\lambda)\|_{\gamma(\lambda)}< L$, $\quad\forall\lambda\in[0,1)$,

where $\|\cdot\|_{\gamma(\lambda)}$ is the norm induced by the Riemannian metric on $T_{\gamma(\lambda)}\mathcal{M}$.

From this, we can say that

$d(\gamma(0),\gamma(\lambda)) \leq \int_{0}^\lambda \|\gamma'(\tau\|_{\gamma(\tau)}\mathrm{d}\tau < \lambda L <L$,

where $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the Riemannian distance function on $\mathcal{M}$.

Therefore, the image of the curve is inside a ball of radius $L$ centered at the first point of the curve:

$\gamma(\lambda)\in B(\gamma(0),L) = \left\{ x\in \mathcal{M} : d(\gamma(0),x) < L\right\},\quad \forall\lambda\in[0,1)$.

Further assume that the ball $B(\gamma(0),2L)$ is entirely contained in $\mathcal{M}$.

**Question** : Is it true that $\lim_{\lambda\to1} \gamma(\lambda)$ exists and belongs to the manifold?

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can simply write $\gamma(\lambda) = \gamma(0) + \int_{0}^\lambda \gamma'(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau$ and the boundedness of the tangent vector norm would allow us to take that integral to the limit $\lambda = 1$. But this way of writing the curve breaks down on the manifold.

Another approach that works for complete manifolds is to take a sequence of $\left\{\lambda_k\right\}\subset [0,1)$ such that $\lambda_k\to 1$ and by the boundedness of the tangent vector we can show that the sequence $\left\{\gamma(\lambda_k)\right\}\subset \mathcal{M}$ is a Cauchy sequence and thus converges to something inside the manifold.

I would really like not to invoke completeness and somehow use the assumption that the ball of radius $2L$ is in the manifold, which excludes that the limit point is no longer on the manifold (think of a manifold that is an open subset of a vector space and that the curve goes up to the boundary of the manifold).

Any idea or comment is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that $B(\gamma(0),2L)$ is "entirely contained within $\mathcal{M}$"? The ball $B(\gamma(0),2L)$ is *defined* to be a subset of $\mathcal{M}$, and it is always well defined, even when it contains curves which do not have limits. It might be useful to consider some simple examples such as $\mathcal{M}=(0,1)$.

Comment: Based on the discussion in the next-to-last paragraph, I think that what ‘the ball $B(\gamma(0),2L)$ is entirely contained in $M$’ is supposed to mean is that every geodesic starting at $\gamma(0)$ may be extended up to every length $\lambda$ such that $\lambda<2L$. (This can be done on any complete manifold, of course, but also on many incomplete manifolds for certain points $\gamma(0)$.)

Comment: Another interpretation could be that we have a complete Riemannian manifold $N$ and $M$ is an open subset of $N$. Then the ball $B(\gamma(0),2L)$ would be taken in $N$, and the assumption that this lies within $M$ is now meaningful. Then the argument about the $\lambda_k$ can be made to work: you get a Cauchy sequence with a limit $p$ in $N$, continuity of the distance function shows that $d(\gamma(0),p)\leq L<2L$, and therefore $p\in M$.

Comment: Thank you both for pointing out the ambiguity/triviality of my assumption. Indeed, the concept of geodesic ball is the one i need. I have to make sure my curve is not ending on the end of the manifold so i need to take the initial point safely away from the border: is this what you mean by "certain points" of incomplete i manifolds?
I also like the perspective of seeing $\mathcal{M}$ as a subset of a complete space $\mathcal{N}$ and considering the ball in $\mathcal{N}$.The distance function of which you invoke continuity is the one of $\mathcal{N}$, right?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your definition of $B(\gamma(0),L)$: it's the set of points ***in $\boldsymbol{\mathcal M}$*** whose distance from $\gamma(0)$ is less than $L$. Similarly, $B(\gamma(0),2L)$ is the set of points  in $\mathcal M$ whose distance from $\gamma(0)$ is less than $2L$. Thus $B(\gamma(0),2L)$ is contained in $\mathcal M$ ***by definition***.

The answer to your question is no, as shown by the following counterexample: Let $\mathcal M$ be the unit disk in $\mathbb R^2$ with its Euclidean metric, and let $\gamma:[0,1)\to \mathcal M$ be the unit-speed geodesic $\gamma(t) = (t,0)$. Then $\|\gamma'(t)\|$ is bounded by $1$, and $B(\gamma(0),2)$ is contained in $\mathcal M$ by the observation in the preceding paragraph, but $\lim_{t\nearrow 1}\gamma(t)$ does not exist in $\mathcal M$.

I think that perhaps what you have in mind is to consider ***geodesic balls*** instead of metric balls. A ***geodesic ball of radius $L$*** around $p\in \mathcal M$ is a set of the
form $\exp_p(B(0,L))$,
*provided* that $\exp_p$ is defined on the entire set $B(0,L) = \{v\in T_p\mathcal M: \|v\|<L\}$ and is a diffeomorphism from that set to its image. What's true is that if there is a ***geodesic ball*** in $\mathcal M$ around $\gamma(0)$ of radius $2L$,
then $\lim_{t\nearrow 1}\gamma(t)$ exists in $M$. The proof is based on the fact that the restriction of $\exp_p$ to the closed ball of radius $L$ around $0$ is a homeomorphism from a compact set onto its image, which is therefore compact, and $\gamma([0,1))$ is contained in this compact set.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this illuminating answer! I hadn't thought that the definition of metric ball does not imply the existence of points that actually are at a distance up to the radius away. In contrast, the geodesic ball does imply that. So if I understand correctly, the image of a complete subset of tangent space through the exponential map is complete? (provided the exponential is defined on that subset)

Comment: @AxelSéguin: No, it's not true that the image of a complete subset of the tangent space is always complete. For example, if $\mathcal M$ is the torus $\S^1\times S^1$ with its flat product metric, there are geodesics whose images are dense in $\mathcal M$. Each geodesic is the image under $\exp_p$ of a line, which is a complete subset of $T_p\mathcal M$. What is true is that images of compact subsets of the domain of $\exp_p$ are compact.